# Emulate JavaScript addition errors with large integers in Python

Tags: javascript, python, web, integer, integer-overflow

kind of an odd request: I'm parsing API parameters from a website. The parameters are being processed by JavaScript on the website to make a request to an API server. The parameters are chosen in a way, where they are added up to form an other parameter (see parameter c):

```
var c = 97210102839047737+67973223506388211;
[...]

var plans = new Array();
$.ajax({

  url: 'info/?c='+c,
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function(data) {
[...]
  }
});
```

JavaScript seems to have problems with large integers and fails to add them correctly. I want to emulate this behaviour with python, since I want to automate the extraction and request process. 
Adding the two numbers with javascript yields:

```
console.log(97210102839047737+67973223506388211)
VM109:1 165183326345435970
```

While Python correctly adds it to:

```
>>> print(97210102839047737+67973223506388211)
165183326345435948
```

Any recommendations how I can emulate this error inside of python?

Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the JavaScript limitation is a consequence of all numbers being stored in floating point representation (ignoring for a moment the typed arrays that JavaScript supports).

So you can get a similar effect if you force Python to perform the addition as floats:

```
print(97210102839047737+67973223506388211)
print(int(float(97210102839047737)+float(67973223506388211)))
```

> 165183326345435948
>   165183326345435968

Comment: you are right, but I need exactly the same representation and not a "similar" one. The API request does not work with a different value. Is there no better way than using a JS interface for this one calculation?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) to represent all its numbers, whether they are integers or actual reals. So what you're seeing is precision artefacts which appear at very large magnitudes.

The way to replicate this in Python is to use floating point numbers as well. Your expression can become:

```
>>> print(float(97210102839047737)+float(67973223506388211))
1.6518332634543597e+17
>>> 1.6518332634543597e+17 == float(165183326345435970)
True
```

This is the same number as above, but with a slightly different presentation. Scientific instead of a string of digits. But the number is the same.

Comment: While 1.6518332634543597e+17 == float(165183326345435970) is True, if I cast the result to an int and then a string, it gives me [...]68 instead of [...]70. I see how they are the same, but for the API request to work I need to receive the same represantion that JS would yield. I was thinking about using a JS interface, but I feel like it would be overkill to import JS just for this one calculation. Is there no easier way?

Comment: That _is_ strange. If you do a `% 10` on the sum of the floats, you get `8.0` instead of `0`. I think it might actually represent the number as is. I'll have a think if there's anything more that can be done.